# automatização de geração de gráficos com seaborn está criando colobars repetidas

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

Estou com o seguinte problema: Eu tenho uma base de dados que consiste em um array 2D de medidas que variam com o tempo. Para cada medida de tempo, eu preciso gerar um gráfico de mapa de cores para serem unidos posteriormente em um gif ou video. Até o momento eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

'''
==================================== TESTS ==================================
'''

Xaxis = np.array([2,6,10,14,19,24,28,32,35])
Zaxis = np.array([0,2,4,6,8,12,16,20,22,23])
tempo = np.array(list(range(0,3)))
medida = np.random.rand(len(Xaxis)*len(Zaxis)*len(tempo))
dados = []

for k in range(0,len(tempo)):
    for i in range(0,len(Xaxis)):
        for j in range(0,len(Zaxis)):
            dados.append([Xaxis[i],Zaxis[j],medida[i+j],tempo[k]])       
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dados,columns=['x','z','medida','tempo'])
df = df.sort_values(['tempo','x','z'])
df_grouped = df.groupby('tempo')

index = 0

df_to_plot = pd.DataFrame(data=df_grouped.get_group(index))
df_to_plot = df_to_plot.drop(['tempo'],axis=1)
df_to_plot = df_to_plot.pivot('x','z','medida')

sns.set_theme(font='Times new Roman', font_scale=1.2)
palette = sns.color_palette('flare',as_cmap=True)
ax = sns.heatmap(df_to_plot, cmap=palette)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='z')
fig = ax.get_figure()
title = 'teste=%i' %(index)
fig.savefig('img/' + title + '.png', dpi=300)
```

Este código funciona perfeitamente, porém eu preciso, na verdade, que o `range` do `tempo` vá de 0 a 100 (coloquei 0 a 3 apenas para facilitar os testes).

O problema vem agora: Para gerar os gráficos, eu apenas comentei a linha do `index` e substitui por um `for` que vai iterar dentro do `tempo` (é claro, corrigindo a identação no código abaixo disso):

```
# index = 0
for index in tempo: 

    df_to_plot = pd.DataFrame(data=df_grouped.get_group(index))
    df_to_plot = df_to_plot.drop(['tempo'],axis=1)
    df_to_plot = df_to_plot.pivot('x','z','medida')
    
    sns.set_theme(font='Times new Roman', font_scale=1.2)
    palette = sns.color_palette('flare',as_cmap=True)
    ax = sns.heatmap(df_to_plot, cmap=palette)
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='z')
    fig = ax.get_figure()
    title = 'teste=%i' %(index)
    fig.savefig('img/' + title + '.png', dpi=300)
```

Entretanto, os gráficos gerados vem com uma colorbar a mais a cada passo, como no exemplo abaixo (último gráfico gerado).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O curioso é que, se eu mudar o valor do `index` manualmente, o gráfico fica exatamente como eu esperava. Mas é inviável para mim fazer assim pois, como falei, serão 100 gráficos cada vez que eu tiver que rodar esse script.

Alguém tem ideia de como corrigir?
Obrigado

Comment: acrescente duas linhas no final do for para ver se muda alguma coisa: `del fig` e `del ax`

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo problema.

Comment: vc quer uma imagem (arquivo) para cada heatmap ou uma única imagem (arquivo) com todos os heatmaps? Acredito que os heatmaps estão se sobrepondo.

Comment: Você tentou usar o `plt.subplot`?

Comment: @PauloMarques usando o subplots eu consegui enxergar um erro que eu estava cometendo na hora de criar o dataframe que fazia os valores ficarem iguais. Acabou resolvendo dois problemas com esse comando, obrigado!

Comment: @AdamBasílio Se puder quando tiver um tempo, escreva uma resposta você mesmo com a solução. Alguém futuramente pode ter o mesmo problema e ter uma resposta (ao invés de procurar nos comentários) ajudaria mais rapidamente esta pessoa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido:

O código corrigido ficou assim:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
'''
==================================== TESTS ==================================
'''
Xaxis = np.array([2,6,10,14,19,24,28,32,35])
Zaxis = np.array([0,2,4,6,8,12,16,20,22,23])
tempo = np.array(list(range(0,4)))
medida = np.random.rand(len(Xaxis)*len(Zaxis)*len(tempo))
dados = []

for x_value in Xaxis:
    for z_value in Zaxis:
        for tempo_value in tempo:
            dados.append([x_value, z_value, tempo_value])

for index in range(0,len(medida)):
    dados[index].append(medida[index])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dados,columns=['x','z','tempo','medida'])
df = df.sort_values(['tempo','x','z'])
df_grouped = df.groupby('tempo')

for index in tempo:

    df_to_plot = pd.DataFrame(data=df_grouped.get_group(index))
    df_to_plot = df_to_plot.drop(['tempo'],axis=1)
    df_to_plot = df_to_plot.pivot('x','z','medida')
    
    sns.set_theme(font='Times new Roman', font_scale=1.2)
    palette = sns.color_palette('flare',as_cmap=True)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax = sns.heatmap(df_to_plot, cmap=palette, annot=True)
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='z')
    
    fig = ax.get_figure()
    title = 'teste=%i' %(index)
    fig.savefig('img/' + title + '.png', dpi=300)
    
    del fig
    del ax  
    del df_to_plot
```

O que foi feito: apenas foi adicionada uma linha `plt.subplots()` antes de gerar a figura.

Aproveitando: havia um erro na hora de construir o DataFrame que fazia os valores plotados ficarem repetidos. Isso foi corrigido reformulando os `dados` da seguinte forma:

```
for x_value in Xaxis:
    for z_value in Zaxis:
        for tempo_value in tempo:
            dados.append([x_value, z_value, tempo_value])

for index in range(0,len(medida)):
    dados[index].append(medida[index])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dados,columns=['x','z','tempo','medida'])
df = df.sort_values(['tempo','x','z'])
df_grouped = df.groupby('tempo')
```

Provavelmente existe alguma forma melhor de corrigir isso sem ter que usar dois loops, mas eu não consegui pensar em nada.

Obrigado @PauloMarques pela ajuda.